# Многопоточное приложение python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Я хочу сделать простой каркас многопоточного приложения, которое выводит строку и засыпает на нужное время. Вот примерный код:

```
import threading
import thread
from threading import Lock
import sys
from random import randint
import time

my_lock = Lock()
class printer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, string):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.string = string
    #with my_lock:
    #   print string
    def run(self):
        sys.stdout.write(self.string + '\n')
        sleep_time = randint(1, 10)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)


max_threads = 5
f = open("strings.txt", "r")
data = f.readlines()
data_count = len(data)
print data_count
threads = []
i = 0
flag = True
curr_threads = 0

while(flag == True):


    if(i >= data_count):
        flag = False

    if(flag != False):
        curr_threads = len(threads)
        while(curr_threads < max_threads):
            print i
            data_string = data[i]
            t = printer(data_string) 
            threads.append(t)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            i = i + 1
            if ( i >= data_count):
                break

    for thr in threads:
        t_id = str(thr.ident)
        print "checking " + t_id
        if thr.is_alive():
            t.join()
            print "handling"
            threads.remove(t)
```

- во-первых почему-то засыпает основной поток
- во-вторых я не знаю как правильно обрабатывать работающие потоки

Я думал, что нужно по всем работающим потоком пройтись и если они `isAlive` то сделать `join` и удалить его из списка и так далее. Но `join` блокирует основную программу, поэтому если какой-то поток долго "спит" то это непродуктивно, да и удалить из списка у меня не получается:

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Как правильно разрулить ситуацию?

Comment: вы итерируете по thr, а используете t, который остался из другого цикла

Comment: @Etki, да, спасибо, не обратил внимания. Но все же, как правильно завершать? Если делать так: for thr in threads:
  thr.join()
  threads.remove(thr), то один зависший поток будешь мешать породить новый.

Comment: Это сильно зависит от задачи - вы можете ждать через join, не ждать вообще, объявить потоки демонами и не заботиться о них вообще. Если вам нужно продолжать работу в основном потоке, то просто скомандуйте тредам остановиться, и они через какое-то время это сделают. join - это принудительное формирование состояния, когда некоторый поток уже завершился.

Comment: @Etki, ну мне в общем-то нужно чтобы в текущий момент времени было запущено N потоком, поэтому я и делал цикл, в котором завершенные убираю, а потом добавляю сколько нужно чтобы в результате в данный момент работало N потоков.

Comment: Вам в таком случае не нужно дожидаться их завершения, надо просто убрать умершие и заменить их свежими

Comment: @Etki, то есть если isAlie false то threads.remove(thr) сделать для этого потока?